# How do I disable KDE Wallet?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 15.04, kwallet, kde5

KDE Wallet keeps popping up whenever try to add or remove connections in the Network Manager. I would like to disable the KDE Wallet system altogether.

In Kubuntu 14.04 I could disable KDE Wallet from *System settings* → *Account Details* → *KDE Wallet*. However, in Kubuntu 15.04 I can't find any option to disable KDE Wallet anymore.

I've removed the wallet from KDE Wallet's interface and now it crashes upon launching it. I have already tried deleting the `~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/kwallet.kwl` file, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've disabled KDE Wallet (because it always asked my password after sync my google calendar with the KDE calendar app) changing the password to a blank password. KDE Wallet will ask you if you're sure cause it's no secure to save an empty password. It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not really disabled in that sense, because it will still save all passwords through KDE Wallet. However, the result about popping up disappears with an empty password indeed.